# What does this formula mean in excel? (A cell equals a range)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office

I see the following formula in a Excel spread sheet and can not understand... Can anyone explain what the test condition "N5=N4:N741" mean?

```
=MIN(IF(N5=N4:N741,K4:K741))
```

I made some experiments and still cannot get a clue...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is an array formula.

What this does is takes the minimum of the range K4:K741 where the value in N4:N741 equals the value in N5.

Let's look at a smaller example. K4:N9 is shown below.

```
    K L M N 
  ----------
4 | 4     2
5 | 8     7
6 | 3     4
7 | 2     1
8 | 7     9
9 | 1     7
```

The expression `N5=N4:N9` is true in row 5 and row 9 since both of those match N5 (value = 7), giving the array `{False,True,False,False,False,True}` Thus `IF(N5=N4:N9,K4:K9)` will return `{False,8,False,False,False,1}` since the `True` values are replaced by the corresponding row in column K. The `MIN()` function will then ignore the `False` parts and return the minimum of the corresponding values in column K (the value 1 since 1 < 8).

Comment: First time encounter an array formula.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it returns an array of true and false values.   I also believe the true shows up for the 3 because it is the third item in the array. but that is a guess on my part.

{false, false, true, false,false}

If you change your 5 in E1 to a 1, it will return a true.

Research all of many things excel

Comment: I would change to a v lookup